# Load array data in a graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Having data in an array I fill the graph with a loop - writing every recordset with a statement into the graph. This leads to several database operations for every single MERGE command per loop. Is there a chance to write a complete array in a graph without having a code based loop (single statement) but with one statement that writes the complete array? This would reduce a lot of overhead.

Now:

```
Foreach (tt AS zz)
{ // Merge one single data record of the array }
```

Better:

```
MERGE ARRAY ((node A[key]) -[relation[key]]- (node B[key]))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a collection of input data (with elements like: `{a: 123, b: 234, r: 345}`) as a `data` [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypher-parameters), this single query should do what you want:

```
UNWIND {data} AS d
MERGE (a:A {prop_a: d.a})
MERGE (b:B {prop_b: d.b})
MERGE (a)-[:FOO {prop_r: d.r}]->(b)
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer - I am back on track :)